# Placement of adjective “only”

Tags: grammaticality, word-order, modifiers

I have the following sentence and three versions to write it:

> - Ensure string *only* contains printable ASCII characters.
> - Ensure string contains *only* printable ASCII characters.
> - Ensure string contains printable ASCII characters *only*.

All versions look valid too me and all tell me the same, but what is the actual difference (if any) and which one would be the best to stress the point best?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's clearest if you place the word "only" in front of the word it modifies. In this case:

> "Ensure the string contains *only* printable ASCII characters."

For more info, see [this WikiHow post](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-the-Word-Only-Correctly).

Comment: Thank you, Nicole. Less than optimally placed "*only*" is one of my pet peeves (but only one).